# Выборка - Linq, Entity Framework (Many-to-many)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

Имеется две таблицы "CarsSet" и "MotorSet" со связью многие ко многим. Третья (связывающая таблица в EF не видна). Помогите составить нижеуказанный запрос SQL в Linq:

```
SELECT *
    FROM   [dbo].[CarsSet] AS [Extent1]
    Inner JOIN [dbo].[CarsMotors] AS [Extent2]
    on CarsSet.id = CarsMotors.cars_Id
    Inner Join MotorSet
    on CarsMotors.Motors_Id = Motorset.id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
context.Cars.SelectMany(car => car.Motors, (car, motor) => new { Car = car, Motor = motor });
```

или наоборот:

```
context.Motors.SelectMany(motor => motor.Cars, (motor, car) => new { Car = car, Motor = motor });
```